# Let $L$ be algebraic curve. which theorem says that $L$ is a piecewise ${C^\infty }$ curve? -

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be algebraic curve. which theorem says that $L$ is a piecewise ${C^\infty }$ curve?

Comment: Well it's defined by polynomials and therefore has singularity set of lower dimension, and so finitely many points.  I realize that's not a theorem, but it's pretty intuitively evident isn't it?

Comment: @GregoryGrant - I don't understand .Please more guide. What is 'set of lower dimension'?

Comment: An algebraic curve is one that is the zero set of a bunch of polynomials.  In an easy case for example, the zero set in $\Bbb R^2$ of a polynomial of two variables.  For example $x^2+y^2=1$ gives the circle of radius one centered at the origin, so that circle is algebraic.  And nothing is smoother than the graph of a polynomial.  They may have isolated singularities, but at most finitely many points.  The rest is $C^\infty$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant - Thanks for this answer. What happen, if there were infinite  isolated points?

Comment: There can't be infinitely many isolated points on an algebraic curve.  That would be like a non-zero polynomial of one variable having infinitely many zeros.

Comment: @GregoryGrant - Can we say that in these points ,tangent fails to exist?

Comment: You could have tangents at a cusp point.  Like on this curve, there's a tangent at that cusp, but it's just not smooth: https://calculus7.files.wordpress.com/2016/01/screenshot-2016-01-27-at-12-14-23-am.png?w=840

Comment: @GregoryGrant _ This lins is faild

Comment: @HUK What exactly does "lins is faild" mean?  Is that English?

Comment: @GregoryGrant - Oh, I'm sorry "This link is failed".

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that.  The link works for me.

Comment: @GregoryGrant - Please more explain for "There can't be infinitely many isolated points on an algebraic curve. That would be like a non-zero polynomial of one variable having infinitely many zeros".

Comment: @H.S It's not trivial to prove this, but I think it follows from Bezout's theorem.  Sorry my algebraic geometry is a bit rusty.